# Why I cant dereference a reference of a Rust array?

Tags: arrays, rust, reference

I extracted this example from my actual issue:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![2u8, 4, 8];
    let vec_ = vec.as_slice();
    let y = Box::new(*vec_);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

My intention is to transform `&[u8]` to `[u8]`. I tried to dereference it by `*` but I got error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:22
  |
4 |     let y = Box::new(*vec_);
  |                      ^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required by `std::boxed::Box::<T>::new`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     let y = Box::new(*vec_);
  |             ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: all function arguments must have a statically known size
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
```

Although the compiler give noted [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait). I read it carefully but cant get useful information to help me to solve my question: how to transform a `&[u8]` to `[u8]`?

Comment: That's not an array. Array ≠ slice ≠ vector.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do, but `let y = vec.into_boxed_slice();` would fit the types you appear to be reaching for.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster. It's exactly want I need. U save my day!